# Truncate text and get text that isn't shown in the viewable frame of label ! (Paging of text)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uilabel

I have a long text containing line breaks and paragraph breaks; and I want to be able to create pages of the text. 
The problem that I am facing is that I am unable to separate out the text that is visible on the page; from the text that goes beyond bounds of the page. 
I was able to get the label size that can display all the text via using sizeWithFont:

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [string sizeWithFont:_lbl.font
                                       constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

**Now, I wants to be able to separate out the visible and non visible text and create pages on the basis of it.**

Any kind of help will be very much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this question here:

[How to split long NSString into pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812692/how-to-split-long-nsstring-into-pages)